# How to Animate Mask to Hide/Reveal 3D Object

Tags: modifiers, transparency

So, I'm new to Blender and I'm trying my best to complete my first project. I've modeled a logo in 3D: it's similar to a winding film strip, but a solid color (color A on the top of the film strip and color B on the bottom of the film strip) instead of textured.

My end goal is to have this 3D object with an animated mask of sorts, so that it wipes down the length of the film strip to the end side, revealing the logo completely, and then the loop starts back over from the start side of the film strip, hiding the logo completely. Essentially, you can think of this as a Loading Screen icon of sorts. Just a continuous loop where the logo is revealed along the path and then hidden along the path. (edit: Here's a quick mockup of the different stages of the animation.)

[image]

Is this something I can do with an animated boolean? That seems to be something I've come across that might work, but I'm not sure. I've attempted to apply a Boolean modifier to a test Cube to see if it interacts properly with my Bezier Curve mesh and I have no results. Here's a screenshot of my scene and properties.

[image: Breakdown of Scene Collection and Boolean Modifier]

If you have any advice on a technique or tutorial I can use, I am happy to do some more digging into this. Just looking to turn this project around soon and needing some direction.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Some kind of sketch of the desired start-mid-end points would really help here.

Comment: Good call. I've added a quick mockup of the progression. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for an extruded curve with an animated end point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Gorgious has commented](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229834/how-to-animate-mask-to-hide-reveal-3d-object/229849#comment388903_229834), no need for a Boolean here.

You can use the native extrusion, and mapping range, of a curve:

[image]

The start and end points of the extrusion can be set, and key-framed.

To get the 2-sided material, you can use a *Geometry* node in the shader, to discriminate between front and back-facing shading points:

[image]

Yours would probably be a bit more sophisticated.. but this is the result, in the viewport:

[image]

Comment: Robin, how can you only keep one output (Backface) for your Geometry node?

Comment: @moonboots Ctrl-H toggles reveal of unused fields / sockets.

Comment: @moonboots Ah! I thought the shortcut was the only way! (I've got to lean the Node Wrangler moves, myself)

Comment: no I didn't mean there was another way, I meant I already saw the trick but didn't know it was Ctrl H  ;)

Comment: Nailed it. This is so super helpful. Thank you for your helpful reference images and GIFs too. I was able to knock this out easily – way easier than I thought it would be. So, thanks again!